# Weird Title from another Page

Tags: php, html

For some reason I am getting "MySQL Config Page" as my title, even though I have this *nowhere* on my page. Why is this?

```
<?php
include "mysql_config.php";
$con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
$org_id = mysql_real_escape_string(html2txt($_GET['org_id']));
$resorgname = mysql_query("SELECT org_name from organization WHERE org_id='".$org_id."'");
if (!$resorgname) {
    die('Invalid query, please contact administrator');
}
while ($orgnamerow = mysql_fetch_array($resorgname)) {
    $org_name = $orgnamerow['org_name'];
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head><title><?php ECHO $org_name; ?></title></head>
    <body>
        ...
```

Here is the generated page source for one of the pages:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head><title>MySQL Config Page</title></head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head><title>Letsgo</title></head>
    <body>
...
```

Comment: As a sanity check, did you try hard coding $org_name to be something else?

Comment: What's the actual HTML output (view source)?

Comment: What is in "mysql_config.php" ?

Comment: It's possible that you're setting `$org_name` in `mysql_config.php` as Nanne implies. Is `$org_id` set to a valid ID? If not, then `$org_name` won't be (re?)set in that block of code.

Comment: $org_name is not set in mysql_config.php, and when I use print_r, it is returning the result I want.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an issue in you mysql_config.php that you included. The browser will take the first head part that it encounters. My suspicion is the included page is causing this.

Just looked at the output HTML and your mysql_config is printing the HTML. It should purely do config. Try require_once("mysql_config.php"); and remove any HTML from the config php.

Answer (score 1):

It's getting the title for the page from the MySQL query you are performing. `$org_name` comes from the array `$orgnamerow` (set by the while loop, which goes through the MySQL rows from your query), which is most likely the first MySQL row on the `organization` table.

So the title is coming from `org_name` in your `organization` table.

Comment: Which should not be MySQL Config Page, as that's not in the database at all!

Comment: The only other reason it's being set as that is that you have `<title>` in mysql_config.php.

Comment: I do have <title> in mysql_config.php

Comment: That is why your title is 'MySQL Config Page'. This is because it's before the other `<title>` tag, so the browser will use this one rather than the other. Remove the `<title>` tag in mysql_config.php and your title will show correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `mysql_config.php` is a page you use for displaying in its own right, which I suspect is why you have HTML in there (maybe you are using it to display the settings, or something).

Therefore, while it may have your MySQL settings in it, you can't really use it in the way you have. A solution is strip all HTML out of `mysql_config.php` and jsut have configuration in it. If you're using the current `mysql_config.php` file for other things, then create a new file - e.g. `mysql_display.php` - and include `mysql_config.php` into that.

If you're not using `mysql_config.php` for anything other than config, then there's no reason to have any HTML in it at all.